# GLSL Fragment Shader pixel color issue

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a texture on a plane, I then modified pixels to get this image

[image: base image]

After I got this image I want to select eyes and color them red, the way I went about is to select the pixels in specific area (based on uv coords) and if those pixels are white, make them red.

I have following fragment shader code

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
uniform float uTime;
uniform vec2 uRes;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec2 vUv;

vec4 getEyePixel(vec2 uvCoords, vec4 pixelColor){
  float xUpperLimit = 0.25;
  float xLowerLimit = 0.115;
  float yUpperLimit = 0.72;
  float yLowerLimit = 0.68;

  float xLowerCheck = step(xLowerLimit, uvCoords.x);
  float xUpperCheck = step(uvCoords.x, xUpperLimit);
  float yLowerCheck = step(yLowerLimit, uvCoords.y);
  float yUpperCheck = step(uvCoords.y, yUpperLimit);
  
  float check = xLowerCheck * yLowerCheck * xUpperCheck * yUpperCheck;
   
  return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) * check + (1.0 - check) * pixelColor;
}

void main() {

  vec4 img = texture2D(uTexture, vUv);
  float darkness = 0.7;
  vec4 modified = vec4(step(darkness, img.x), step(darkness, img.y), step(darkness, img.z),1.0);
  modified = modified * (1.0 - step(0.6,modified.x)) * (1.0-step(0.6, modified.y));
  modified = modified * (1.0 - step(0.85, modified.z));
  vec4 final = getEyePixel(vUv, modified);

  gl_FragColor = final;
}
```

this works and gets me following picture

[image: eye area selected]

The last thing, in my getEyePixel function, I send current pixelColor as variable. And I wanted to add one last check to only paint pixels that are currently white -> to red. So I added one more step function check. I believe, and this is possibly where Im messing up, that pixelColor is rgba values between 0.0 and 1.0 ? For pixel to be white it should have rgb values quite high near ~0.9 and higher. Since my picture contains at that point only white and black pixel I do a step function with 0.3 and pixelColor.x.

So getEyePixel code is now

```
vec4 getEyePixel(vec2 uvCoords, vec4 pixelColor){
  float xUpperLimit = 0.25;
  float xLowerLimit = 0.115;
  float yUpperLimit = 0.72;
  float yLowerLimit = 0.68;

  float xLowerCheck = step(xLowerLimit, uvCoords.x);
  float xUpperCheck = step(uvCoords.x, xUpperLimit);
  float yLowerCheck = step(yLowerLimit, uvCoords.y);
  float yUpperCheck = step(uvCoords.y, yUpperLimit);
  float isPixelWhite = step(0.3, pixelColor.x);
  
  float check = xLowerCheck * yLowerCheck * xUpperCheck * yUpperCheck * isPixelWhite;
   
  return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) * check + (1.0 - check) * pixelColor;
}
```

Problem here is that isPixelWhite is always 0.0 because resulting image is base image, like so. There are no red eyes.

[image: base image]

So there must be something wrong how I am trying to select white pixels in the eye area.
this line

```
 float isPixelWhite = step(0.3, pixelColor.x);
```

Ive tried .x .y .z and some other values, but clearly I'm selecting wrong. How can I fix this?